# Disable button clicks once the correct answer is clicked?

Tags: jquery, events, click

Think multiple choice quiz with multiple questions... Here's how my html is organized.

```
<div class="question" id="question1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="name name1 col-XS-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3" data-answer="correct">Answer 1</div>
            <div class="name name2 col-XS-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">Answer 2</div>
            <div class="name name3 col-XS-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">Answer 3</div>
            <div class="name name4 col-XS-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">Answer 4</div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="question" id="question2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="name name1 col-XS-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">Answer 1</div>
            <div class="name name2 col-XS-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">Answer 2</div>
            <div class="name name3 col-XS-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3" data-answer="correct">Answer 3</div>
            <div class="name name4 col-XS-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">Answer 4</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery so far...

```
$(".name").click(function(){
    if($(this).data("answer")){
        $(this).addClass("correct"); //just changes color of div
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("incorrect"); //just changes color of div
    }
});
```

I've tried using .off() on the parent element but that didn't work. I've seen solutions with unbind but is that an old solution? I've seen some CSS pointer-events solutions that may be incompatible with old browsers. So what's the best way to disable #question1's answers once the correct one has been clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.off()` to unbind the click on all sibling divs with:

```
$(".name").click(function () {
    if ($(this).data("answer")) {
        $(this).addClass("correct"); //just changes color of div
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("incorrect"); //just changes color of div
    }
    $(this).siblings('div').off('click')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LUWe3/)**

I hope no one looks at the source before taking your test...

Comment: Ha! Yes, it's just for fun so I'm not worried about cheating. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".question").on('click', '.name', function(){

    var $e = $(this);        // Current choice
    var $p = $e.parent();    // Parent element

    // Check if the question has already been answered
    if ($p.find('.correct').length !== 0 || $p.find('.incorrect').length !== 0) {
        alert('You only have one guess!');
        return;   
    }

    // Add class
    $e.addClass($e.data('answer') ? 'correct' : 'incorrect');

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DDf5Z/)